# Trying to install PIPX on linux

Tags: python, installation, pip, pipx

python3 -m pip install --user pipx. I ran this command but changed python3 to python, because that's what the trouble shooting instructions told me. However when I run the command it say I am using an old version of python 2.7. I checked my python version and in fact it is 2.7. So I looked up how to upgrade. But it turns out that if I type python3 --version it outputs a higher version to meet the requirements. So I tried to just run "python3 -m pip install --user pipx" with the 3 but it says no module named pip. Does this have to do with my path? Why is my computer not recognizing pip.

Comment: What;s your *OS* version?

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate,

Comment: I just flagged it. thanks for showing me the ropes